# ruby on rails: true button to boolean datatype in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, boolean

I have a column in database with datatype boolean

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :services do |t|

      t.boolean :recommend, :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I want use to click a button or check yes or no to a form so when user submits a review, they would recommend and change the database to `true`.

How would I do such a thing?

I have a button:

```
<div class="field-container"><%= f.button :recommend %></div>
```

If user clicks on it, I'm not sure if it'll save true to database? Do I need to add more to this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not sure? It's quite easy to test if it does or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to have button and not a checkbox for the boolean field, you can have a checkbox which is styled like a button.

http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/4/

and then

```
<%= f.check_box :recommend %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a boolean value, you can very easily use a `form_for` [`check_box`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) to accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
<%= f.check_box :recommend %>
```

This will generate markup for a form where the value of `params[:recommend]` in your controller action will be understood to be a boolean value when updating (or creating) the record through ActiveRecord.